# DB Migration in iOS?

Tags: ios, sqlite, dbmigrate

I have an app in which I haven't set the SQLite version in and now I want to upgrade the app but I have some column changes in the new iPA. How can I implement the DB Migration in iOS? I am using FMDB for the database.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a constant which version point to the version increments.
Each time the database updates increment the counter.

On app launch call the following code :

```
DatabaseMigrator *dbMigrator = [[DatabaseMigrator alloc]
                                initWithDatabaseFile:
                                [AbstractRepository databaseFilename]];

//for development only - toggle this to force the new database over
//dbMigrator.overwriteDatabase = YES;

[dbMigrator moveDatabaseToUserDirectoryIfNeeded];

[dbMigrator migrateToVersion:CURRENT_SCHEMA_VERSION];

BOOL marked = [FileUtils addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:[AbstractRepository databasePath]];

if (marked) {

    NSLog(@"succesfully Marked do not back up");

} else {

    NSLog(@"failed Marked do not back up");
}
```

Comment: Where to get the DBMigrator class? What to write in it?